# Aggregate a property containing an array of objects, in a tree data structure

Tags: javascript, recursion, tree

I have a tree structure like below (there is no depth limit, generally not more than 6 sub-levels). Each node has a `workItems` property, that is an array of `workItem` objects.

I'd like to aggregate the `workItems` at each node, so that a node contains its own workItems and all it's descendance's workItems.

An example of below structure, the node id `11` would have the workItems:

```
    [{ id: 'wi2' },
     { id: 'wi3' },
     { id: 'wi4' }, 
     { id: 'wi5' }] // aggregated from node `111`
```

And node `1` would have absolutely all the workItems of the tree.

**javascript**

```
const traverse = (tree) => {
    const stack = [ tree ]

    while (stack.length) {
        const curr = stack.pop()

        // do something here, I guess

        stack.push(...curr.children)
    }
}
```

**Tree structure**

```
    {
        id: '1',
        title: '1',
        workItems: [
            { id: 'wi1' }
        ],
        children: [
            {
                id: '11',
                title: '11',
                workItems: [
                    { id: 'wi2' },
                    { id: 'wi3' },
                    { id: 'wi4' }           
                ],
                children: [
                    {
                        id: '111',
                        title: '111',
                        workItems: [
                            { id: 'wi5' },
                        ],
                        children: []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                id: '12',
                title: '12',
                workItems: [
                    { id: 'wi6' }                           
                ],
                children: [
                    {
                        id: '121',
                        title: '121',
                        workItems: [
                            { id: 'wi7' },
                            { id: 'wi8' }
                        ],
                        children: []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: is the tree an object (like the example) or an array?

Comment: There is a way to do this without *true* recursion. I'll post a demo shortly.

Comment: why not a recursion?

Comment: @NinaScholz, no reason. Im not all that good at it is all. Studying your solution however is instructive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a depth first search and hand over the parent array of `workItmes` for pusihng the nested items.

```js
const
    getWorkItems = ({ workItems, children = [] }) =>
        (workItems.push(...children.flatMap(getWorkItems)), workItems);

var tree = { id: '1', title: '1', workItems: [{ id: 'wi1' }], children: [{ id: '11', title: '11', workItems: [{ id: 'wi2' }, { id: 'wi3' }, { id: 'wi4' }], children: [{ id: '111', title: '111', workItems: [{ id: 'wi5' }], children: [] }] }, { id: '12', title: '12', workItems: [{ id: 'wi6' }], children: [{ id: '121', title: '121', workItems: [{ id: 'wi7' }, { id: 'wi8' }], children: [] }] }] };
  
getWorkItems(tree);

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: What would be your approach if the data structure was flat: an `array` of nodes with a `parent` prop pointing to parent node instead of `children`, eg: `tree = [ { id: '121', parent: '12', title: '121', workItems: [ { id: 'wi7' }, { id: 'wi8' }] } , { ... },  { ... } ]`

Comment: @GregForel: I'd suggest that you ask that as a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version that creates a new tree rather than modifying the current one in place.  (I'm a big fan of immutable data.)  Note that the `workItems` are still shared by reference, both within a single tree and between the original and derived one.

```js
const addAllDecendents = (
  {workItems, children = [], ...rest}, _, __,
  kids = children .map (addAllDecendents)
) => ({
  ... rest,
  workItems: [... workItems, ... kids .flatMap (child => child .workItems)],
  children: kids,
})

const tree = {id: "1", title: "1", workItems: [{id: "wi1"}], children: [{id: "11", title: "11", workItems: [{id: "wi2"}, {id: "wi3"}, {id: "wi4"}], children: [{id: "111", title: "111", workItems: [{id: "wi5"}], children: []}]}, {id: "12", title: "12", workItems: [{id: "wi6"}], children: [{id: "121", title: "121", workItems: [{id: "wi7"}, {id: "wi8"}], children: []}]}]};

console .log ('New tree:', addAllDecendents (tree))
console .log ('Original tree:', tree)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

The only unusual part of this answer is the use of the parameters `_` and `__`.  These are used to mimic the placeholder feature of many languages.  They are simply parameters meant to point out that the argument supplied here will not be used.  In this case, it's because we `map` the children over this function, but `Array.prototype.map` supplies two additional arguments in addition to the array value: the index and the original array.

We could handle this in several other ways.

We could pass a function to `map` which directly recurs and manages the arguments itself:

```js
const addAllDecendents = (
  {workItems, children = [], ...rest},
  kids = children .map (c => addAllDecendents (c))
) => // ...
```

But there's a problem with that: we could then not use `addAllDescendents` as a callback to another `map` invocation elsewhere.  That is, something like `const enhancedTrees = trees.map(addAllDescendents)`  .This might well not be a problem, but it's a restriction.

The other alternative, and probably the safest one, would be to change to use a block instead of an expression as the function body, and move the assignment of `kids` into there:

```
const addAllDecendents = ({workItems, children = [], ...rest}) => {
  const kids = children .map (addAllDecendents)
  return {
    ... rest,
    workItems: [... workItems, ... kids .flatMap (child => child .workItems)],
    children: kids,
  }
}
```

I personally like the first version better than this because I prefer working with expressions to working with ordered statements (the assignment of `kids` followed by the `return` statement.)  But I'm pretty sure that's a minority view, and either one works fine.

### Update

Here's one additional version, which skips the still-not-universal-`flatMap` with a `map`-then-`reduce` equivalent:

```js
const addAllDecendents = ({workItems, children = [], ...rest}) => {
  const kids = children .map (addAllDecendents)
  return {
    ... rest,
    workItems: [
      ... workItems, 
      ... kids .map (child => child .workItems).reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), [])
      ],
    children: kids,
  }
}
```

Comment: Scott, for some reason, I could not get it to work, and I thought Nina's answer is a bit easier. Thanks again for taking the time to answer.

Comment: Nina's answer is certainly easier, and, as always from Nina, excellent.  Mine was designed to satisfy one additional restriction: I prefer not to mutate data, instead creating new structures.  I'm not sure why it didn't work for you, but it's possibly that you're working in an environment without `flatMap`.  If that's it, I added one more version which avoids that.